# .Net Core EF doesn't allow me to enter same Foreign Key

Tags: asp.net-core

I have got a Model with Foreign Key. Some how .NET Core EF doesn't let me enter the same Foreign key twice to the table.

```
public class DolsMcaClientModel
{
    [Key]
    public int DolsMcaClientID { get; set; }

    public int DolsMcaItemID { get; set; }
    public virtual DolsMcaItemModel DolsMcaItemModel  { get; set; }

    public int ClientID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int FileID { get; set; }
    public virtual FileModel FileModel { get; set; }
}
```

In this table **DolsMcaClientID** is my Identity Column and **DolsMcaItemID** is my Foreign column. **DolsMcaItemModel** is my navigation property.

I can't enter the same DolsMcaItemID for different client. 
DolsMcaItemID  acting like a primary key in the table. But it is not.
[image]

```
ERROR: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.DolsMcaClientModels' with unique index 'IX_DolsMcaClientModels_DolsMcaItemID'. The duplicate key value is (1).
```

**If I delete DolsMcaItemID 1 item from the table, then i can add new entry to the table with DolsMcaItemId 1, but only once with any clientID... i can't enter DolsMcaItem 1 for with any other clientID**

My SQL Table create query is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DolsMcaClientModels](
[DolsMcaClientID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[DolsMcaItemID] [int] NOT NULL,
[ClientID] [int] NOT NULL,
[FileID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DolsMcaClientModels] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DolsMcaClientID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DolsMcaClientModels]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_DolsMcaClientModels_DolsMcaItemModels_DolsMcaItemID] FOREIGN KEY([DolsMcaItemID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[DolsMcaItemModels] ([DolsMcaItemID])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DolsMcaClientModels] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_DolsMcaClientModels_DolsMcaItemModels_DolsMcaItemID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DolsMcaClientModels]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_DolsMcaClientModels_FileModels_FileID] FOREIGN KEY([FileID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[FileModels] ([FileID])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DolsMcaClientModels] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_DolsMcaClientModels_FileModels_FileID]
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [UNIQUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments) index *[IX_DolsMcaClientModels_DolsMcaItemID]* on that column is preventing you from committing another record with the same *[DolsMcaItemID]*.

Fix is to drop the unique index:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DolsMcaClientModels] DROP INDEX [IX_DolsMcaClientModels_DolsMcaItemID];

CREATE INDEX [IX_DolsMcaClientModels_DolsMcaItemID] ON [dbo].[DolsMcaClientModels] ([DolsMcaItemID])
```

Don't forget to scaffold your db context to remove the constraint from code.